# Object.Assign() without overriding existing properties

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ecmascript-6

forgive the title as I'm not sure if this is even possible.

I have a json model like so

**json model 'data'**

```
{
   "RegisteredAddress": "1 street, Sw3 1aq",
   "TradingAddress": "2 street, sw4, 5ad",
}
```

that I want to map to a model that looks like this

**AddressModel.ts 'addressModel'**

```
{
   "RegisteredAddress": null,
   "TradingAddress": null,
   "PreviousAddresses": ["Previous Address Street, RH10 1BG"]
}
```

Is it possible for me to use **Object.Assign(this.addressModel, data);** without overriding the existing populated properties on the Address.ts model. I essentially want to just populate the fields that are in the json model and not override any exsiting properties that don't exist on the json were assigning. Final result should be

**AddressModel.ts 'addressModel'**

```
{
   "RegisteredAddress": "1 street, Sw3 1aq",
   "TradingAddress": "2 street, sw4, 5ad",
   "PreviousAddresses": ["Previous Address Street, RH10 1BG"]
}
```

Understand that I could map these properties manually but this is an example and im working with a much bigger model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `Object.assign` for this, you could assign everything to a new object with `this.addressModel` listed last:

```
this.addressModel = Object.assign({}, data, this.addressModel);
```

That way, `this.addressModel` "wins" when it has properties that are also in `data`.

> Understand that I could map these properties manually but this is an example and im working with a much bigger model.

The size of the model isn't important here, it's a loop whether it's in `Object.assign` or in your code. The loop in your code would look something like:

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(data)) {
    if (!(key in this.addressModel)) { // Or `!this.addressModel.hasOwnProperty(key)` or `!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.addressModel, key)` depending on what you want to check and your style
        this.addressModel[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou! so this essentially created a copy of the AddressModel.ts and then re-assigns it back to the original model without overriding?

Comment: @jjharrison - If you mean the first cole block, effectively, yes -- it overwrites the object reference in `this.addressModel` with a new object, but any own properties on the original `this.addressModel` will have their values unchanged in the new object. Only properties that didn't conflict will come from `data`. The *second* code block just updates the existing object directly (again, only if it doesn't have the property).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - "The size of the model isn't important here, it's a loop whether it's in Object.assign or in your code. " Can you point to a reference where I could see how Object.assign is implemented? I did not expect Object.assign to be using a loop...

Comment: @paroxyzm - It's in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object.assign). I can't think of any other way it could be implemented. :-)